# FabricJS canvas objects group is being hidden when adding its clone to another canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, fabricjs

I try to export a group of objects from a canvas to svg. To do so, I clone the group in another canvas (which will have the same height/width of the group).It works very well. But the problem is the group becomes hidden in the original canvas, I don't know why.

here is the code:

```js
    this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('meCanvas', {
        preserveObjectStacking: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 200,
        backgroundColor: '#1F1F1F',
        canvasKey:'azpoazpoaz'
    });
    let newID = (new Date()).getTime().toString().substr(5);
    let rect = new fabric.Rect({
        fill: 'red',
        width: 48,
        height: 32,
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        myid: newID
    });

    let newID1 = (new Date()).getTime().toString().substr(5);
    let text = new fabric.IText('Text', {
        fontFamily: 'Times',
        fontSize: 18,
        fill: 'white',
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        myid: newID1,
        objecttype: 'text'
    });

    this.__canvas.add(rect);
    this.__canvas.add(text);
    this.__canvas.renderAll();

    $('#generate').click((e)=>{

        let obj = this.__canvas.getActiveObject();
        if(!obj) return;

        let obj1 = $.extend(true, {}, obj);
        this.tempCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('tempCanvas', {
            canvasKey:'efsdfsd',
            preserveObjectStacking: true,
            height: obj1.getScaledHeight(),
            width: obj1.getScaledWidth()
        });
        obj1.left= 0;
        obj1.top=0;
        this.tempCanvas.add(obj1);
        let mySVG = this.tempCanvas.toSVG();
        //console.log(this.tempCanvas.toSVG());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <div style='display: inline-block'>
        <div>
            <canvas id='meCanvas' ref='meFabric'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id='generate'>Generate the SVG</button>
        </div>
        <div style='display: inline-block'>
            <div id="rect"></div>
            <div id="recttext"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you select both the text and the red rectangle at once, and then click on the button "Generate the SVG", and then click on the canvas again, the group will disappear. And I don't know why.

Please how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy an object use [obj.clone()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#clone) instead of `$.extend`

***EXAMPLE***

```js
this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('meCanvas', {
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
  height: 300,
  width: 200,
  backgroundColor: '#1F1F1F',
  canvasKey: 'azpoazpoaz'
});
let newID = (new Date()).getTime().toString().substr(5);
let rect = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: 'red',
  width: 48,
  height: 32,
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  myid: newID
});

let newID1 = (new Date()).getTime().toString().substr(5);
let text = new fabric.IText('Text', {
  fontFamily: 'Times',
  fontSize: 18,
  fill: 'white',
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  myid: newID1,
  objecttype: 'text'
});

this.__canvas.add(rect);
this.__canvas.add(text);
this.__canvas.renderAll();

$('#generate').click((e) => {

  let obj = this.__canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (!obj) return;
  obj.clone(function(clonedObj) {
    let obj1 = clonedObj;
    this.tempCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('tempCanvas', {
      canvasKey: 'efsdfsd',
      preserveObjectStacking: true,
      height: obj.getScaledHeight(),
      width: obj.getScaledWidth()
    });
    obj1.left = 0;
    obj1.top = 0;
    this.tempCanvas.add(obj1);
    let mySVG = this.tempCanvas.toSVG();
  })


  //console.log(this.tempCanvas.toSVG());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div style='display: inline-block'>
    <div>
        <canvas id='meCanvas' ref='meFabric'/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id='generate'>Generate the SVG</button>
    </div>
    <div style='display: inline-block'>
        <div id="rect"></div>
        <div id="recttext"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```